# Oracle count по условию

Tags: oracle, count

Всем доброго времени суток! Столкнулся с такой проблемой, есть запрос который возвращает

```
| SOT  | KUT  | K1 | K2 | YADRO | GR  |
|------|------|----|----|-------|-----|
| 2055 | 1,31 | 0  | 3  | 2     | 101 |
| 2055 | 1,31 | 0  | 3  | 2     | 101 |
| 2055 | 1,31 | 0  | 3  | 2     | 103 |
| 2055 | 1,31 | 1  | 0  | 1     | 100 |
| 2055 | 1,31 | 0  | 3  | 3     | 102 |
| 2055 | 1,31 | 0  | 3  | 3     | 102 |
```

Где столбцы K1 и K2 расчётные, K1 показывает сколько различных групп(GR) принадлежащих ядру(YADRO) 1 посещает сотрудник (SOT), K2 показывает сколько различных групп(GR) НЕ принадлежащих ядру(YADRO) 1 посещает сотрудник (SOT).
Ядра содержат только уникальные группы, в двух разных ядрах группы не повторяются.
Запрос

```
select sot,
round(sum(time)over(partition by sot)/25920,2) as Кутил,
case when yadro=2 then count(distinct gr)over(partition by sot,case when yadro=2 then 0 else 1 end) else 0 end as K1,
case when yadro!=2 then count(distinct gr)over(partition by sot,case when yadro!=2 then 0 else 1 end) else 0 end as K2,

... from ...
```

Проблема в том что запрос возвращает значения с нулями а нужно чтобы было как то так

```
| SOT   | KUT   | K1    | K2    | YADRO     | GR    |
|------ |------ |----   |----   |-------    |-----  |
| 2055  | 1,31  | 1     | 3     | 2         | 101   |
| 2055  | 1,31  | 1     | 3     | 2         | 101   |
| 2055  | 1,31  | 1     | 3     | 2         | 103   |
| 2055  | 1,31  | 1     | 3     | 1         | 100   |
| 2055  | 1,31  | 1     | 3     | 3         | 102   |
| 2055  | 1,31  | 1     | 3     | 3         | 102   |
```

---

Чтобы не было нулей а были общие цифры во всех столбцах, буду очень благодарен за помощь, сразу говорю обёртки предлагать только в крайнем случае, хотелось бы обойтись без лишних подзапросов и т.д.

Comment: А зачем нужен `case when yadro=2 then` именно он и возвращает 0 там где `yadro<>2`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Не уверен , но стоит попробовать вот так :

```
count(distinct case when yadro=2 then gr else null end )over(partition by sot) as K1
```

Comment: Спасибо тебе огромное добрый человек! То что нужно! Самое интересное то, что я пробовал делать подобный запрос, правда я там проставил в over другие условия и забыл прописать distinct и следовательно не выдавал как надо. Вообщем спасибо!